# Warning : select expects an Array value for its binding, but got String

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, vue-router

the application i am working on includes 3 or 4 pages where the user is asked to enter some data in various fields (input, select). If the user wants to go back to a page, the previous data needs to be displayed (I get it from the store, using computed properties).
It works well on input type fields, however i get a warning with select type fields :

```
[Vue warn]: <select multiple v-model="tax"> expects an Array value for its binding, but got String
```

Here is an extract of the code in the template section of the selectTax.vue file :

```
<select v-model="tax" multiple="multiple">                      
  <option value="tax1">Tax1</option>
  <option value="tax2">Tax2</option>
  <option value="tax3">Tax3</option>
```

Here is an extract of the code in the script section of the selectTax.vue file :

```
 tax: {
      get() {
        return this.$store.getters.taxtype;
      },
      set(value) {
        this.$store.commit("setTaxType", value[0]);
      }
    }
```

The problem is that the computed property tax is a string, not an array.

Is there any proper way to fix it ? Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

When using `<select multiple` the data model is not a string, but an `array`.

This is because the user can select more than one option.

You have 2 options:

- update the data type for `this.$store.getters.taxtype` to be initialized with an array (empty most likely) and update

```
set(value) {
  this.$store.commit("setTaxType", value);
}
```

- or remote `multiple` from the select

Comment: Well, i removed the multiple nature of the select since the user can in fact only select one option. And it fixes it. Thanks for helping.